# how to take time from the server?

Tags: php

The countdown works but is subtracted from the date in the system. How to improve it.

How to download the date from the server and calculate from that date

```
<?php
    $date = date('M d, Y H:i:s', strtotime('19-6-2018 15:00:00')); 
    $date1 = date('M d, Y H:i:s', strtotime('8-3-2019 15:37:25'));  
        ?>      

        <script>    
            var count = new Date("<?php echo $date;?>").getTime();
            var count1 = new Date("<?php echo $date1;?>").getTime();
        </script>
        var timer1 = new Timer('demo', count);
        var timer2 = new Timer('demo1', count1);       
        function Timer(id, countDownDate) {
          this.interval = setInterval(tick, 1000);       
          function tick() {
            var distance = countDownDate - now;
var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 *
```

Comment: Please complete your code example - it looks like you cut some code at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the time from server with Ajax.

**JS**

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'YOUR-FILE.php',
  method: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    var count1 = data.first;
    var count2 = data.second;
  }
})
```

(If you are not working with jQuery, you could use Fetch API.)

**PHP**

```
<?php
$date = date('M d, Y H:i:s', strtotime('19-6-2018 15:00:00')); 
$date1 = date('M d, Y H:i:s', strtotime('8-3-2019 15:37:25'));  
echo json_encode(
    array(
        'first' => $date,
        'second' => $date1
    )
);
```

Comment: @user9805028 jQuery